# How to do a translator?

Tags: python, django

I am currently coding my first website, which is a translator in an invented language. You input a random phrase and it should get translated in the invented language. Here's the code for the translation:

```
class TranslatorView(View):
    template_name=  'main/translated.html'
    def get (self, request, phrase, *args, **kwargs):
        translation = ""
        for letter in phrase:
            if letter.lower() in "a":
                if letter.isupper():
                    translation = translation + "U"
                else:
                    translation = translation + "u"
            elif letter.lower() in "t":
                if letter.isupper():
                    translation = translation + "A"
                else:
                    translation = translation + "a"
            elif letter.lower() in "c":
                if letter.isupper():
                    translation = translation + "G"
                else:
                    translation = translation + "g"
            elif letter.lower() in "g":
                if letter.isupper():
                    translation = translation + "C"
                else:
                    translation = translation + "c"
        return render(request, 'main/translator.html', {'translation': translation})
    def post (self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        phrase = request.POST.get('text', 'translation')
        translation = phrase
        context = {
            'translation': translation
        }
        return render(request,self.template_name, context)
```

Template where you input the phrase:

```
{% extends "base.html"%}

{% block content%}
<form action="{% url 'translated' %}" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
    <div class="form-group">
        <center><h2 class = "display-3">TRANSLATE YOUR DNA CHAIN</h2></center>
        <br>
        <br>
        <textarea class="form-control" name='text' id="exampleFormControlTextarea1" rows="6"></textarea>
        <br>
        <button type='Submit' class= "btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block">Translate</button>


    
      </div>   
</form>
{% endblock content %}
```

Template where the text should get translated:

```
{% extends "base.html"%}

{% block content%}

<div >
    <center><h2 class = "display-4">DNA TRANSLATED SUCCESFULLY INTO</h2></center>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>

    <center>
        <h3>
        {{ translation }}
    </h3>
    </center>
       

    
</div>   

{% endblock content%}
```

Here's the thing, when I translate the phrase and redirects me to the translated template, the text that I wrote (Example: dadada) appears without being translated.

[image]

I have no clue where the error is. If someone knows the error, please answer because I'm genuinely stuck and It's been two months without progress.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem in your code is in the post method, you are just taking the phrase sent and returning it back in the context.

I've made some small changes in the view to make the code more readable, like separating the "translation" process in a function and the characters for the substitution in a dictionary.

```
from django.views import View
from django.shortcuts import render


class TranslatorView(View):
    template_name = 'main/translated.html'

    mapper = {
        "a": "u",
        "t": "a",
        "c": "g",
        "g": "c"
    }

    def translate(self, phrase):
        translation = ""
        for letter in phrase:
            if letter.lower() in self.mapper:
                translation += self.mapper[letter.lower()].upper() if letter.isupper() else self.mapper[letter]
        return translation

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return render(request, 'main/translator.html')

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        phrase = request.POST.get('text', 'translation')
        return render(request, self.template_name, {'translation': self.translate(phrase)})
```

One last suggestion, don't use the `<center>` tag in your html as it is deprecated, better use the css `text-align: center;` property.

Comment: OMG It looks so much better and it has finally worked. Thank you so much. I hope one day I can be as good at coding as you.